# The introduction to the translation of Al Charizi

Tags: rambam, translation

In Shem Hagdolim in the section on Pirush Hamishna, the author quotes the introductions of various translators of the Rambam's Pirush Hamishna.

> [שם הגדולים מערכת ספרים אות פ [לט]](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C)/%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91/%D7%A4) פירוש המשנה של הרמב"ם: 
>   ובהקדמת המעתיק לסדר זרעים החכם ר' יהודה בן שלמה הספרדי הידוע בן חריזי כתב שלכבוד ק"ק מארשיליא נתרצה להעתיק.

Where can i get hold of these introductions? I am particularly interested in the one by Al Charizi.

Comment: @Ploni he is one of the translators of the Rambam's Pirush hamishna from arabic to Lashon Hakodesh perhaps i will edit that into my question

Comment: If you mean *Al-harizi* you can find it [here](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/הקדמת_הרמב%22ם_למשנה_(אלחריזי_מהדורת_המבורגער)).

Comment: @Oliver thank you for the correction. I am really interested in the introduction composed by al charizi himself... thank you (i edited the question to that effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Al-harizi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Alharizi)’s introduction to his translation of Maimonides’ commentary can found be found [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14308&st=&pgnum=239&hilite=) in the standard Vilna edition of Berachot.

Comment: isn't this the rambam's introduction, translated by al charizi? the shem hagdolim seems to be referring to an introduction authored by the translator himself, in which he describes how he was pressured to do the translation. however this is pretty impressive research. (there is a similar introduction to the chovos halevavos, authored by ibn tivn

Comment: Ah, indeed. I’ll change the answer accordingly. It’s in the Vilna Shas - no impressive research for that :)